# How to add different class objects into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add 2 class objects in which they are an extension of another class into
an ArrayList. The codes are as follows:

Student class

```
public class Student
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

UndergradStudent class

```
public class UndergradStudent extends Student
{
    private int examMark;

    public UndergradStudent(String firstName, String lastName, 
        int examMark)
    {
        // parameters for Student class
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.examMark = examMark;
    }
}
```

PostgradStudent class

```
public class PostgradStudent extends Student
{
    private int thesisMark;

    public PostgradStudent(String firstName, String lastName, 
        int thesisMark)
    {
        // parameters for Student class
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.thesisMark = thesisMark;
    }   
}
```

While I am able to add them into 2 different `ArrayList`, is it possible to combine them into 1 `ArrayList`? If so, how should I define the type for it?

The reason I had wanted to have 1 `ArrayList` is to minimize the amount of duplicated code lines.
Eg. in my Main class below, instead of writing the print statement twice, I can write once instead.
And I will also be having more methods that access either of the 2 class objects and printing out the same statements...

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        UndergradStudent ugs = new UndergradStudent("Day", "Parker", 65);
        PostgradStudent pgs = new PostgradStudent("Pete", "Loomis", 78);
        
        ArrayList<UndergradStudent> ugsArr = new ArrayList<UndergradStudent>();
        ArrayList<PostgradStudent> pgsArr = new ArrayList<PostgradStudent>();
        
        ugsArr.add(ugs);
        pgsArr.add(pgs);
        
        // For UndergradStudent
        for (int i=0; i< ugsArr.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("ugs: " + ugsArr.get(i).getName());
        }

        for (int j=0; i< pgsArr.size(); j++)
        {
            System.out.println("pgs: " + pgsArr.get(j).getName());
        } 
    } 
}
```

Also I tried creating an ArrayList as `ArrayList allStudents = new ArrayList();`, and I will get an error for the print statement as it cannot find `getName()`..

Appreciate for any advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: Use the abstract type:

```
List<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

One of the fundamentals of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is basically that all types may safely be identified and dealt with using their abstract type.

Indeed, using the type `List<Student>` (as I have) instead of `ArrayList<Student>` is another example, and best practice.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought that the extension `Student` cannot be used as I am targeting on the other 2 classes. Noted on that, I  will need to brush up more on my OOP!

Comment: I just realized but why is `List<Student>` preferred over `ArrayList<Student>`?

Comment: @j.hall always prefer the most abstract bound for everything. In this case, it matters not *what specific* implementation of List the list is; it matters only that is *an* implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of parent class as below. Which will allow you to add both child elements to single list. As below:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can create reference of `ArrayList` as well, but it's always preferable to go with `List`.

Comment: Thank you, noted on that. I wasn't aware that the parent class can be used as I presume that the type needs to be 'linked' to the class objects or so..

Answer (score 1):

Since UndergradStudent and PostgradStudent are inherited from Student class they can be referenced using student class so you can just use ArrayList of type Student Object that will accept all the entries of Student, UndergradStudent, PostgradStudent.

```
List<Student> allStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
```